# how can I delete a pkg file on a mac?

Tags: file, pkg

I have a .pkg file for Malwarebytes on my computer. I can't send it to the trash nor delete it in any other manner. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: When you drag it to the trash, what message pops up or what happens? What does “delete in in any other manner” mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

- From the terminal type `sudo rm -f <package name>`. You should be able to remove it as root. Reboot in safe mode if necessary.
- Download and install [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/). It has functionality for removing difficult to remove files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's not being used by Installer.app, and make sure it's not part of a disk image, which might be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Open trash and right clock on the package you want to delete. One of the items displayed is "delete immediately". Select that option.

[image]